# NSTimer won't trigger function in object

Tags: object, swift2, nstimer

I am making a simple game, and every second, I need the player to lose a food "point". Currently, I have the declaration like so.

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: player, selector: Selector(player.foodLoss()), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

And I never hear from the timer again, it has, to the best of my knowledge, no effect on the rest of the app. My `Player` class is as follows

```
class Player: Character {
    var food = 100
    init(startingHealth: Int = 100, startingFood: Int = 100) {
        super.init(imageNamed: "Player", entityName: "Player")
        food = startingFood
        sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
    }
    func adjustFood(amountToAdjustBy adjustAmount: Int) -> Bool{
        if food + adjustAmount <= 100 {
            food += adjustAmount
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    func foodLoss() {
        food -= 1
        print("food lost")
    }
}
```

I get no error when running the code. The only thing that happens is `player.food` is completely unaffected. Any help with my problem would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You never call `timer` in your class... how do expect it to deduct anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the selector. Right now you would actually call the method `foodLoss` when creating the timer and use the return value (Void) as the method the timer should call all the time. It therefore will not do anything.

To fix that you need to provide a different selector. For example use `Selector("foodLoss")` instead:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: player, selector: Selector("foodLoss"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

To make that work you might have to mark the `foodLoss` function as `@objc`:

```
@objc func foodLoss() {
    food -= 1
    print("food lost")
}
```